# Node catch() error doesn't show file the error occured

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, node-inspector, node-debugger

I am using the `new` `--inspect` parameter in node to debug my application with `Chrome Developer Tools`. I have a very basic `catch` at the end of my promise chain but the errors returned are not showing clearly where they came from.

Am I able to see which file the error originated in?

```
  leagues(app).getLeagues(passData)
    .then(teamsApi.getNorsemenTeams)
      .then(filterBarGamesIndex)
    .then(gamesApi.getNorseGames)
    .then(gamesApi.getFilteredTeams)
    .then(function (passData) {
      res.render('games', {
        title: 'Results',
        passData: passData,
        type: req.originalUrl.split('/')[2]
      })
    })
      .catch(function(err) {
          console.error(err); //Line 35
      });
}
```

[image]

And directly from the console the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Intermediate_Division_2' of undefined
    at /var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk/app/controllers/filterBar/fixturesIndex.js:27:62
    at Array.filter (native)
    at module.exports (/var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk/app/controllers/filterBar/fixturesIndex.js:25:42)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Comment: Based on the error, it appears your error occurred in `filterBarGamesIndex`

Comment: I agree, but no such file exists in my system :/

Comment: What browser are you using? If you are using Firefox you could try `console.log(err.lineNumber)` as said on the [Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

Comment: @brennanenanen This is Node.js.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you are correct, weird that I was searching for `fixturesIndex`, i invalidated my cache in `phpstorm` and then it found the file.

Comment: It seems that the `bug` if you can call it that is with using the `--inspect` it does not display the errors correctly

Comment: @brennanenanen some tips are [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render), [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports), and `process._tickCallback` (in the stacktrace), which is visible in basically every Node.js error I've ever seen.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to dump more information about the exception as in

console.log( err.stack );

Comment: That results in very similar error sadly `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Intermediate_Division_2' of undefined
    at /var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk/app/controllers/filterBar/fixturesIndex.js:27:62
    at Array.filter (native)
    at module.exports (/var/www/beta.norsemanfc.co.uk/app/controllers/filterBar/fixturesIndex.js:25:42)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)`

Comment: As `filterBar/fix‌​turesIndex.js` isn't a real file at all. I believe this might be something to do with my using `jade` as my templates?

Comment: That's not "very similar". You've got more locations there.

Comment: No its actually identical, my mistake for only showing the error in the devtools. Please see updated questions